# Permissions problem with Wix Custom Action and Burn bootstrapper

Tags: permissions, wix, custom-action, bootstrapper, burn

I have a package that needs to be installed with elevated administrator privileges. However, this installer includes an uninstall **custom action** to run a clean-up executable, which must be run as the local user.

This all works fine for the generated MSI (install and uninstall), but when I wrap the MSI up in a Burn bootstrapper, the uninstall **custom action** is instead run as the administrator - and hence fails...

My application must be installed “perMachine”, and so in my *Product.wxs* I have my package setup with

```
InstallPrivileges="elevated"
InstallScope="perMachine"
```

However, this application's uninstaller includes an uninstall **custom action** to run a clean-up executable, which must be run as the local user (since it looks for a file in the user’s App-Data). So I’ve set the **CustomAction** to

```
Impersonate="yes" Execute="immediate"
```

And have:

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="UninstallCleanup" Before="RemoveFiles">
      (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")
    </Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This builds my MSI file, which I can then install on my machine. When I then run the uninstall, either via the Control Panel or manually (msiexec /x MyInstaller.msi /l* Testing.log), I am prompted for an admin password, the application is uninstalled, and the custom action is run as the local user. Everything perfect.

BUT I need to wrap this MSI up in a WiX Burn bootstrapper EXE that also installs pre-requisites (the VC runtime) before running my MSI package. Now when this **Package Bundle** is installed, and then uninstalled via the control panel, my MSI uninstall **custom action** is run as the *administrator* rather than the *local user* - and so fails.

In my *Bundle.wxs* file I have:

```
<PackageGroup Id="PP_Package">
  <MsiPackage
      Compressed="yes"
      EnableFeatureSelection="no"
      SourceFile="$(var.PP_MSI_PATH)"
      Permanent="no"
      DisplayInternalUI="no"
      Visible="no"
      Vital="yes">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
  </MsiPackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

And

```
<PackageGroup Id="VCRedist">
  <ExePackage Id="vcRedist_x86"
              Cache="yes"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="$(var.VCREDIST_X86_LOC)\$(var.VCREDIST_X86_FILE)"
              Name="Redist\$(var.VCREDIST_X86_FILE)"
              InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
              Protocol="burn">
    <ExitCode Value="1638" Behavior="success" />
    <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

And then:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="VCRedist" />
  <RollbackBoundary Vital="yes" />
  <PackageGroupRef Id="PP_Package" />
</Chain>
```

What have I got wrong? Is the issue something like: WiX Burn detects that the MSI is perMachine and so starts it using elevated admin, so that the custom action interprets Impersonate="yes" as meaning the administrator rather than the local user?

Any help, explanations and solutions would be most welcome.

Comment: How did you determine that your custom action runs as "Administrator"? Are you sure it does not actually run as the user who launched the setup, just with elevated rights?

Comment: Good question - took a bit of digging! In the end I changed the cleanup-utility-EXE (run by the custom action) to write its own log file to the user's App-Data. Then when I ran the uninstall as a standard user (and was prompted for the admin's pswd), this log file appeared in the *admin user's App-Data*, with a log-msg indicating it could not find a "target file" (which is part of its clean-up functionality) within the App-Data. But this "target file" **does exist** in the *standard user's App-Data* (i.e. in the App-Data of the standard user who launched the uninstall via the Control Panel).